# Multiple columns as a range - Worksheet_Change - alternative for conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, range, multiple-columns, conditional-formatting

I don't know how to set a range for multiple columns, about 150 of them, or every 4th column starting with a Q column.
I tried to set each column individually but the line of code is too long and cannot be split (the first 15 columns are listed in this code).
I hope you understand what the problem is.

This is my code:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

r = Target.Row

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Q3:Q5000, U3:U5000, Y3:Y5000, AC3:AC5000, AG3:AG5000, AK3:AK5000, AO3:AO5000, AS3:AS5000, AW3:AW5000, BA3:BA5000, BE3:BE5000, BI3:BI5000, BM3:BM5000, BQ3:BQ5000, BU3:BU5000")) Is Nothing Then

    If Target.Value = "Likvidirana partija" Or Target.Value = "likvidirana partija" Then
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 241)
        
        Else
        
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        Else

    If Target.Value < Cells(r, 7).Value Then
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Target.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        Else
    
    If Target.Value > Cells(r, 7).Value Then
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        Target.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    
End If

End Sub
```

I'm new here and this is my first post, so I apologize if I did something wrong.

Comment: check `target.column>16` and then `(target.column -17) mod 4 = 0` perhaps?

Comment: I'm relatively unfamiliar and new to the VBA, so I don't know how to use this.
Can you help me with changing this part of the code, ie how to use this part of your code?

`If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Q3:Q5000, U3:U5000")) Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It's not tested so could be some glitches.

As it stands your code does not remove any existing formatting.

Would suggest you do some reading on If-Else structures in VBA.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column < 17 Or Target.Column > Range("BU1").Column Then Exit Sub 'column
If Target.Row < 3 Or Target.Row > 5000 Then Exit Sub                       'row
If (Target.Column - 4) Mod 4 <> 0 Then Exit Sub                            'every 4th from 17

Dim r As Long

r = Target.Row

If Target.Value = "Likvidirana partija" Or Target.Value = "likvidirana partija" Then _
                            Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 241)
If Target.Value = "" Then Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

If Target.Value < Cells(r, 7).Value Then
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Target.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
ElseIf Target.Value > Cells(r, 7).Value Then
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    Target.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: SJR thanks a lot!
Your code didn't work properly, so i changed it a bit and now it works perfectly.
I know the code won't help me with existing formatting, this is for future entries in excel tabel.
Should I post the final code in answer to my question?

Comment: You could do. What did you have to change?

Comment: I had to change the if statemate and add else because there must be only one criterion. I also had to put (Target.Column - 5), with -4 was not a good column.

Comment: This will fail if more than 1 cell is changed, eg by copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column < 13 Then Exit Sub                     'column
If Target.Row < 3 Or Target.Row > 5000 Then Exit Sub    'row
If (Target.Column - 5) Mod 4 <> 0 Then Exit Sub         'every 4th from 17

Dim r As Long

r = Target.Row

    If Target.Value = "Likvidirana partija" Or Target.Value = "likvidirana partija" Then
        Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 241)
    Else
                            
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Else
    
            If Target.Value < Cells(r, 7).Value Then
                Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                Target.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
            
                If Target.Value >= Cells(r, 7).Value Then
                    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
                    Target.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End If
                
            End If
            
        End If
        
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This will fail if more than 1 cell is changed,  eg by copy/paste

Comment: This is true, but in this table the data are entered values individually for each cell separately.

Comment: Until one day someone copy/pastes a block.  You can simply ignore this with `If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Thanks, I will add this just in case.